# coregraphics on gnustep ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu-12.04, quartz-2d, gnustep

so im thinking about porting some logic written for my ios app to the server.
I am building a view hierachy and then rasterizing it to bitmaps

I have used [chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/) to successfully port the relevant bits to  mac os.

and now I would like to try porting this to ubuntu using since GNUstep has an open implementation on AppKit. I managed to get the hello world app working. However, It seemed strange to me than the following throws errors on compiling.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Random",@"hello from GNUStep Appkit!",@"close this window",@"Another Button",nil);
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc]init];
    view.layer;
    CGRect rect;
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
hello.m: In function ‘main’:
hello.m:10:6: error: request for member ‘layer’ in something not a structure or union
hello.m:11:2: error: unknown type name ‘CGRect’
```

It seems strange to me that these errors should be thrown, as I believed coregraphics to sit below AppKit. Am I missing a particular module in gnustep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, CoreGraphics is not implemented in GNUstep; I believe though that [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) has an implementation.

The error `error: request for member ‘layer’ in something not a structure or union` refers to the expression `view.layer`, which you intended to return the `layer` property from the `view` object. That syntax is from Objective-C 2.0, which wasn't supported out of the box with GNUstep, last I knew; check [ObjC2FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) for information about enabling it (and what its limitations on GNUstep are).

In the meantime, you can instead use the original Objective-C syntax: `[view layer]`.

Comment: GNUstep's CoreGraphics implementation is called Opal.

Comment: thanks for the info. guess i have to read up more on gnustep history. thanks fred for the heads up. after investigating opal and cocotron, i find that neither cocotron nor opal's implementation of corgraphics is complete enough for my needs :( Considering the amount of additional work i have to do to TRY and get it to port successfully with no guarantees of success, i might as well write something to run on ubuntu from scratch :/